# How should I write this sentence in grammatically correct way?

Tags: grammar, questions

This is my sentence:

> Do you know what temperature and humidity in your room are?

Should I invert **in your room** and **are**? I don't know, maybe it will be more accurately: "Do you know what temperature and humidity are in your room?"

How should I write this sentence?

Comment: Preferably with determiners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking about specific temperature and pressure, with "in your room" identifying which temperature and pressure you're talking about, so it should "Do you know what **the** temperature and humidity in your room are?" Inverting "in your room" and "are" would imply that there's one temperature, and it takes on different values in different locations, rather than there being different temperatures for different locations.